# matlab: What is done in a array construction "(end:-1:1, :)"

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a definition of two matlab arrays in an existing code:

```
x1 = [
   0.34567854556734  -0.01122679215254
   0.34567854556734   0.01122679215254
  -0.08838834764832   0.08838834764832
   0.08838834764832   0.08838834764832
   0.01122679215254                  0
   0.01122679215254                  0
];

x2 = af(end:-1:1, :);
```

What exactly is the construction "(end:-1:1, :)" in the second array (x2) definition doing?

Answer (score 1):

It effectively reverses the order of the rows of the `af` array. When indexing with `(a:k:b)`, `a` denotes the first index, `b` the last and `k` the step size. Since `end` points towards the last entry of an array `(end:-1:1)` lists the indexes of the array in reverse order.

Check out the [doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/array-indexing.html), the are plenty of examples and explanations.